# Duda sobre puntero a estructura en conexiones TCP/IP

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
// IPv6:

struct sockaddr_in6 ip6addr;
int s;
ip6addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
ip6addr.sin6_port = htons(4950);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:8714:3a90::12", &ip6addr.sin6_addr);
s = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&ip6addr, sizeof ip6addr);
```

Me gustaría saber a qué está apuntando este puntero. Yo supongo que es a todos los elementos de la estructura, pero no estoy seguro de ello.

```
(struct sockaddr*)&ip6addr, sizeof ip6addr);
```

Answer (score 3):

En C no existe el concepto de herencia, por lo que si tu necesitas que una función haga *polimorfismo*, es decir, poder tratar objetos de estructuras diferentes de una forma más o menos homogénea tienes que realizar algunos trucos.

Fíjate que la función `bind` debe recibir un puntero a una estructura de tipo `sockaddr`... mientras que tu estás usando una estructura de tipo `sockaddr_in6`. ¿Por qué funciona esto? El motivo es que ambas estructuras tienen una parte común, como se puede apreciar a continuación:

```
struct sockaddr {
  sa_family_t sa_family;
  char        sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
  sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
  in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
  uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
  struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
  uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
};
```

Fíjate que el primer miembro de ambas estructura es común. `sa_family` será lo que use la API de sockets para identificar la estructura que hay realmente por debajo.

Así para hacer la conversión a la inversa podrías hacer algo tal que:

```
struct sockaddr* sockaddr = GetConfigSocket();
switch( sockaddr->sa_family )
{
  case AF_INET6:
    struct sockaddr_in6* ip6addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)sockaddr;
    // ...

  case /* ... */
}
```

Pues bien, dicho esto podemos responder a tu pregunta:

> Me gustaría saber a que esta apuntando este puntero,yo supongo que es a todos los elementos de la estructura pero no estoy seguro de ello.

En esta parte del código:

```
(struct sockaddr*)&ip6addr
```

Estás obteniendo un puntero de tipo `struct sockaddr` apuntando a tu estructura, que es de tipo `sockaddr_in6` y esto se hace, como hemos visto, para poder proporcionar un único punto de entrada para configurar los diferentes sockets.

Como lo que le facilitas a la función es un puntero lo que estás compartiendo realmente es la región de memoria donde se encuentra tu variable luego, sí, realmente estás compartiendo la estructura al completo.